# jQuery className don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, classname

In these 2 examples the first one work the scond don't.

In the second example I **bind** **dragover** and **dragleave** events to **img** instead of **div** but I want to change **className** for **div**.
The events are correctly detected and no error is raised but **div** does not change its class.

Where is the problem?

```js
//This work

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#framedrag").bind("dragover dragleave", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
        return false;
    });
});
   

//This don't work

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#dragdrop").bind("dragover dragleave", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#framedrag").className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#framedrag
{
   color: #555;
   border: 2px dashed #555;
   border-radius: 7px;
   cursor: default;
}

#framedrag.hover
{
   color: #3fc600;
   border-color: #3fc600;
   border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview-pane">
    <div id="framedrag">
        <div class="preview-container">
            <img id="dragdrop" src="images/upload-picture.png" class="jcrop-preview" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery dragenter or dragover to include children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756176/jquery-dragenter-or-dragover-to-include-children)

Comment: @Difster I have seen this answer but don't help the problem is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `$("#framedrag").attr("class", e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");`

Comment: @user2272143 oh, sure, I was inattentive. Why don't you use simple addClass of jQuery?

Comment: @user2272143 I've edited for `attr` also you can use just `$("#framedrag").removeClass().addClass(e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Actually this worked! $("#framedrag")[0].className
Thank you very much!