# How to show image when dragging file with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, plupload

I'm working on an uploader which uses plupload core api. I designed uploader with css. Now i want to do this:  When user drag a file into the dropzone, dropzone will be blurred. (I can do this with foggy). Beside that, when background is blurred, and image will be visible on the page. ( Like Google Drive Web Site ).

I did this with jquery dragover event. I created an image and set its visibility hidden. When dragover event fired i change to "visible". But when i do this, (image shows and pointer on it) jquery's ondragleave method fired and image is gone. Then dragover fired image is shown, then gone, then... again and again :)

I can't found anything about that problem. Here is the screenshot.
[image: Problem]

And this is how google drive web page seems :
[image]

Comment: Is it the same problem you have?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110353/html5-dragleave-fired-when-hovering-a-child-element

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm dragging files, not elements. If i have to explain with few words, div with image not acting child of dropzone div. When cursor in dropzone div, child div (with img. background) will appear. Then suddenly it's acting foreign div and cursor leaving the dropzone even in dropzone ? I know this is unclear told, sorry for my bad english. Thanks Heejin.