# Why does HTML5 Drag n Drop target child? (Sortable List)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

When I attempt to create a sortable list with HTML5 Drag n Drop, the target of the drop event (`e.target`) is the child of the drop-zone element, rather than the drop-zone element itself. This is bad.

I want the value of `e.target` in the following code to be the `div` which contains `ondrop="drop(event)"` rather than it's `<p>` child.

Link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/dt6ovvzc/) with full example.

```
function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));   
}
```

Is this happening because of event bubbling, or something similar? What is the best fix that will help me create a Drag n Drop sortable list?

Edit: I am looking to understand the native HTML5 and Javascript, not use a jQuery library or some such.

Comment: I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18542687) does explain a bit about the issue

Comment: Your link helped my understand the problem. Here's the quote from your link that pulled it all together: "Because the `dragenter` event is fired on child nodes before the `dragleave` event on the parent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to append to the target element, hence you are facing the  problem.

You should try to insert the element before the target element.

```
function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.insertBefore(document.getElementById(data), e.target.parentNode);
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dt6ovvzc/12/)

Comment: Your answer solves my problem, but why is the `<p>` tag considered a drop-zone when only the parent `<div>` has the drop-zone code? (`ondragover="allowDrop(event)"`)

Comment: Also, is this a correct implementation of the HTLM5 drag and drop standard? Or is it hacky and incorrect in some way?

Comment: a. After you read Quirksmode's [post](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html) on HTML5 drag and drop, you are wary about touching it at all.
b. `e.target` is still the child node - we're just working around that
c. Every other post about sortable HTML5 drag and drop lists contains about 10x more code, so that gets me worrying. What are your thoughts?

Comment: It simply works but you included jquery in your jsfiddle example, while it is not in use. Misleading for beginners!