# How to avoid a child div in react invoking a parent's `onDragLeave` event

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Please see [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-microservice-zkpen?file=/src/App.js:0-957).

I have a parent div that needs to handle for draggable events (such as when a file is dragged over it). When `onDragEnter` is invoked, I want the background color to change. However, I have a child div, which, when hovering over it, invokes the parent div's `onDragLeave` event. I've tried using a ref with this child div to determine if the event target is contained in the child div but that doesn't seem to be working. How can I avoid a child div in React invoking the `onDragLeave` event? Thanks!

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [dragOver, setDragOver] = useState(false);

  const preventDefaults = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  const onDragEnter = (event) => {
    preventDefaults(event);
    console.log('ENTER');
    if (!dragOver) {
      setDragOver(true);
    }
  };

  const onDragLeave = (event) => {
    preventDefaults(event);
    console.log('LEAVE');
    setDragOver(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      data-testid="document-upload"
      onDragEnter={onDragEnter}
      onDragLeave={onDragLeave}
      style={{ 
        background: dragOver ? 'green' : 'red',
        height: '20rem',
        width: '20rem',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{ border: '2px solid blue', height: '10rem', width: '10rem' }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: This is quite a tricky business with HTML5 drag and drop - see this question and answers for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110353/html5-dragleave-fired-when-hovering-a-child-element

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to set `pointerEvents: "none"` in the `style` prop of the child `<div>`, so that all pointer-related events on this div are ignored. That would introduce some limitations, though - like you couldn't bind click events to the child div.

If this doesn't fit within the constraints of your application, you can modify your `onDragLeave` handler to inspect the `relatedTarget` of the event (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget)). If the drag is leaving the parent `<div>` but *entering* a child of the parent, then the `relatedTarget` (i.e. child div), will be *contained* (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)) by the `currentTarget` (i.e. the parent `<div>`)

Here's the code that should work:

```
const onDragLeave = (event) => {
    preventDefaults(event);
    // This condition will be true when the drag leaves the parent for a child,
    // but false when the drag leaves the parent for somewhere else.
    if (event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) return;
    console.log("LEAVE");
    setDragOver(false);
  };
```

See [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-event-solution-nfcme?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: As you commented in your codesandbox ex. the `pointerEvents: "none"` in styles of a child element does the job, thanks!