# IE10 does not appear to like the drop event when dropping a file

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

I have a simple web app that uses the filereader api in HTML5 to accept file uploads through drag and drop.

Upon dragging a file onto the webpage, the correct drag event will fire, but when I drop the file IE simply opens it rather than letting the JS handle it.

The drop code is very basic:

```
this.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
Self.drop(event); //this event is not hit. IE just opens the file!
}, false);
```

Is this a specific limitation of IE10 or could I be doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

You will want to also listen to the `dragenter` and `dragover` events and prevent their default behavior. You'll also want to prevent default behavior in the `drop` event handler as well.

For example you may want to do something like this...

```
var $dropArea = $( "#drop-area" );

$dropArea.on({
    "drop" : makeDrop,
    "dragenter": ignoreDrag,
    "dragover": ignoreDrag 
});

function ignoreDrag( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function makeDrop( e ) {
    var fileList = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files,
        fileReader;

    e.preventDefault();
    if ( fileList && fileList.length > 0 ) {
        fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = handleReaderOnLoadEnd( $( "<img />" ) );
        fileReader.readAsDataURL( fileList[ 0 ] );
    }
}

function handleReaderOnLoadEnd( $image ) {
    return function( event ) {
        $image.attr( "src", this.result )
            .addClass( "small" ) 
            .appendTo( "#drop-area" );
    };
}
```

You can find a working example at this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qsyNW/

Note: You don't have to use jQuery with this like I did. However, if you do use jQuery then you'll need to reference `e.originalEvent` inside the `drop` event handler in order to get at the `dataTransfer.files`.

Comment: I found that in chrome, I could use drag and drop fine handling only "dragover" and "drop", but in IE10 I needed to handle "dragenter" as well and prevent default, otherwise my "dragover" event never fired...

Comment: Additionally: If you're seeing no `files` property when trying your own code but it works with Elijah's, you're probably running a test on your **local** (intranet) webserver. IE10's brain-dead default is to serve intranet content in (in)Compatibility View, which disables features like the `files` property on the `dataTransfer` object. On the wrench menu, go to "Compatibility View Settings" and untick the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" box. Eejits.

Comment: If you don't control the IE config, you can do that in your HTML or via custom HTTP headers. In the HTML, you can put this at the **very top** of `head`: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` (Supposedly some versions will ignore it if it's after anything but `title`. Of course they will. Because that's not broken at all. Further down works for me in IE11; don't have a handy IE10 test box, but I'd put it at the top for safety.) Or, of course, configure your server to send that header in the HTTP.