# IE11: Drag & drop not working

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-11

I cannot get IE11 to honor the `dragOver`, `dragLeave`, and `drop` event handlers I have registered on the drop zone element.

The `dragStart` handler on the draggable items works fine, and so do the `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers on the drop target--just not the drag & drop handlers on the drop target.

FYI, what *ought* to be happening is that you should see output in the F12 tools Console when you

- start the drag,
- drag over the drop target,
- drag out of the drop target, and
- drop on the drop target.

Furthermore, you should see a red outline appear when you drag over the drop target and disappear when you drag out of the drop target.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drag &amp; Drop</title>
<style>
  *[draggable=true] { cursor: move; }
  .activated { outline: 1px solid red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><a href="#" draggable="true">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
<div><a href="#" draggable="true">dolor sit amet</a></div>
<div><a href="#" draggable="true">consectetur adipiscing elit</a></div>
<div><a href="#" draggable="true">Curabitur non semper leo</a></div>
<div><a href="#" draggable="true">Pellentesque habitant morbi </a></div>
<div><a href="#" draggable="true">tristique senectus</a></div>

<p class="drop-zone">
  Drop Here
</p>

<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    function findAll(selector) {
      const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      const nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);
      return nodes;      
    }

    findAll('*[draggable=true]').forEach(function (node) {
      node.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
        const data = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'all';
        event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', data);

        console.log('Drag start: "' + data + '"');
        return false;
      });
    });

    findAll('.drop-zone').forEach(function (node) {
      node.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
        console.log('Mouse over');
        node.style.background = 'pink';
      });
      node.addEventListener('mouseout', function (event) {
        console.log('Mouse out');
        node.style.background = '';
      });

      node.addEventListener('dragover', function (event) {
        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        node.classList.add('activated');

        const data = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        console.log('Drag over: "' + data + '"');
        return false;
      });
      node.addEventListener('dragleave', function (event) {
        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        node.classList.remove('activated');

        const data = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        console.log('Drag leave: "' + data + '"');
        return false;
      });
      node.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        node.classList.remove('activated');
        const text = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        const data = event.dataTransfer.getData('Text');

        console.log('Dropped on: "' + text + '"');
        console.log('  data: "' + data + '"');
        return false;
      });
    });
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note, this was apparently also a problem in IE10, but I overlooked this post with an answer by the ever-dependable Elijah Manor:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742636/ie10-does-not-appear-to-like-the-drop-event-when-dropping-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to get dragopen to fire until I added a listener for dragenter in IE11.  So, give that a try.

```
  node.addEventListener('dragenter', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    const data = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    console.log('Drag enter: "' + data + '"');
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: And that accords with MSDN's documentation: 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms536929(v=vs.85).aspx. 

But MDN makes it sound as if _either_ `dragOver` _or_ `dragEnter` can be handled and still trigger `drop`.